# A study found that the hepatitis C virus can live on surfaces for six weeks. Did they end the study before the seventh week began?

Tags: human-biology, microbiology, virology, infectious-diseases, hepatitis

A study once found that the hepatitis C virus (HCV) can remain infective for six weeks on ordinary household surfaces. You can see the [free full text](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3969546/), or a [summary for busy clinicians](https://www.healio.com/infectious-disease/nosocomial-infections/news/online/%7Ba77304f1-b43e-43bc-a5fe-97128b7236e8%7D/hcv-can-remain-infective-for-weeks-on-inanimate-surfaces).

What happened in the seventh week? Did the virus cease to remain viable, or did the study just end suddenly?

From part B of [this figure](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3969546/#JIT648F1), it looks to me like the study just ended suddenly. But I'm not a biologist, so I'd like to hear your opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The place to find this information would be the Methods section of the paper.

> We spotted 33 µL of plasma spiked with HCVcc on the 24-well plates. They were either immediately tested for viable virus or stored at 4°C, 22°C, and 37°C for up to 6 weeks before testing.

They tested their samples for (up to) 6 weeks. At the time of the 6th week they still found infectious virus. They did not test samples beyond 6 weeks so they can't say anything about infection past that time.

Comment: I appreciate your answer! ❧ I've now asked a follow-up question: ["We know that the hepatitis C virus can live on surfaces for at least six weeks. Maybe longer. The infectivity study ended after just six weeks; why?"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/80094/we-know-that-the-hepatitis-c-virus-can-live-on-surfaces-for-at-least-six-weeks)